# Why did Chava give Adam the fruit to eat?

Tags: sin, trees, parashat-bereishit, adam, eve-chava

For what reason did Chava give Adam fruit from the tree of knowledge to eat?

Comment: "So that she wouldn't die while he would live and marry another" (Rashi, B'reishis 3:6).

Comment: @Fred so many questions! 1) if she didn't die right away from eating it why would she assume she would die at all 2) doesn't that make her pretty evil? 3) who else was around for Adam to marry?

Comment: @Fred Sounds like Romeo and Juliet

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like the exact opposite of Romeo and Juliet (l'havdil!) they chose suicide (sorry, spoiler!) here it seems she is choosing homicide

Comment: @not-vram Those are good questions. That's why I posted as a comment - left unexplained, it would be insufficient as an answer.

Comment: jealousy. the sin of adam contained the 3 roots of all evil as brought down in the mishna in avot - jealousy, lust, and honor take a person out of the world. see this audio http://dafyomireview.com/audio/m04-3_flaws_of_man_and_role_of_jews.mp3 by Rabbi Uziel Milevsky, the former chief Rabbi of mexico who explains it very nicely.jealousy. the sin of adam contained the 3 roots of all evil

Answer (score 7):

In a comment to the OP's question Fred cites the well-known Rashi (see above). The Bartenura on the Torah expands on this Rashi (text borrowed from Sefaria.org, produced here in full):

> ותתן גם לאישה שלא תמות היא ויחיה הוא וישא אשה אחרת. קשה למה נתכונה להרוג את אישה כדי שלא ישא אשה אחרת הרי היא מוספת על חטאתה פשע ללא תועלת י"ל שהיתה סבורה לומר אם יאכל גם הוא ונהיה שנינו מסוכנין למות לא ירצה הקב"ה למחות המין האנושי מעל פני האדמה וישא לפשע שנינו ולא נמות אבל אם אוכל לבד מן העץ. הנה אדם יתקיים וישא אחרת שימציאהו הקב"ה אשה אחרת כשם שהמציא אותה ויתקיים המין האנושי בלעדי ואני אמות לכך האכילה גם לאישה אולי ירוחמו מן השמים לסבה שאמרנו:

My own (loose and off the cuff) translation follows:

"...this is difficult, for why would she intend on killing her husband so that he wouldn't marry another woman, thereby adding to her sin, without any benefit? One can say that she reasoned that 'if Adam ate as well and we were both in danger of dying, God would not want to completely wipe out the human race and would "bear" our sin and not kill us, but if I was the only one who ate then Adam would remain and God would just fashion him another wife the same way He had when He created me, thus ensuring that the species survive, without me.' Thus, she gave Adam to eat hoping for mercy as described above.